# attempted to read or write protected memory. crystal report 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I had created project in `VS 2008` with `crystal report` version 2008 64bit. I run the project in clients and every things works fine.

I upgrade my project by using `VS 2013` with using `crystal report v13`. I run the project in client and it works fine. But error come after few days, when I print a report using print tool in `crystal report`. This error message `View 
attempted to read or write protected memory`.

I can solved the problem by reinstall the `crystal report`, but when I restart the PC, the problem will return.

Is there any one help me to solve this problem.

I am using `Windows 7` 64 or 32 bits, Arabic in all clients PC

Comment: Show some code where exactly it happens.

Comment: the crystal report display the report works fine but the problem show when press print button tool in cystal report for printing in paper > this show as message box